# remove back slash and add protocol

Tags: php, json, api

I'm working a project where require a json api something like

```
{
  "images":[
             {"id":1,"name":"test1","url":"image url"},
             {"id":2,"name":"test2","url":"image url"}
           ]
}
```

but I'm getting different url format and what code I've written that is

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function getJson(){
    $array = array( 'images' => array(array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'test1', 'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test1.jpg'),
                   array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'test2', 'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test2.jpg')));
    return $array;
}
$typeArray=null;
if(isset($_GET['request'])){
    if($_GET['request']=='images'){
        $typeArray=getJson();
    }else{
        $typeArray = array(array( 'status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Invalid request url'));
    }
}else{
    $typeArray = array(array( 'status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Invalid request url'));
}
echo json_encode($typeArray);
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
?>
```

But I'm getting

```
{"images":[{"id":1,"name":"test1","url":"picd.flynox.com\/test\/test1.jpg"},{"id":2,"name":"test2","url":"picd.flynox.com\/test\/test2.jpg"}]}HTTP/1.1
```

I've pushed this changes to testing server http://picd.flynox.com/api/test/images

Comment: why `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];` in the end?

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary,I need url like "http:// picd.flynox.com" but I'm getting "picd.flynox.com" by using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].I mean, how to add protocol like http:// or https:// but I can't hard code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the backslashes you may pass JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES as a second parameter to json_encode() like this:

```
json_encode($typeArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Before php 5.4 you may need to use smth like:

```
str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($typedArray));
```

For the http/https you should use $_SERVER['HTTPS']:

```
'HTTPS'
Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
```

Comment: Thanks @blu, it is working fine.Can u suggest me for making complete url "http:// picd.flynox.com". I'm trying $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but it is not enough.

Comment: I've wrote that in my answer - drop $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and use smth like: _$url = (( 0<strlen($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && 'off'!=$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://picd.flynox.com....';_ Adopt to your needs.